# Why my piecewise function is not working

Tags: plotting

It says `Part 1 of {} does not exist` when I try to plot the vector fields of this piecewise function.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x + 2, x <= -1}, {-x, -1 < x < 1}, {x - 2, 
            x >= 1}}]
    
VectorPlot[{100 *(y - f[x]), -x/100}, {x, -1, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you! I am new to this site and will try to follow the conventions of this  community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please post plain text code so one can copy it. Hard to copy code from images. Unless one uses AI to scan the image and have it convert to Mathematica code.

Try this

```
ClearAll[f, x, y];
f[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{x + 2, x <= -1}, {-x, -1 < x < 1}, {x - 2, x >= 1}}]
VectorPlot[{100*(y - f[x]), -x/100}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You needed to add `?_NumericQ`, to prevent premature evaluation as symbolic. With Numeric, the function is called when `VectorPlot` is ready to replace x with numerical value passed to `f[x]` so it does not see the actual symbolic piecewise definition with the {} in it only the numerical value returned.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! But what happens to my code?

Comment: @Bill that was a typo. OP posted an image so I had to write it from scatch.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I have changed the picture into codes.